# How do I detect scrolling in a buefy b-dropdown component?

Tags: buefy

I tried passing in a function through @scroll then tried to detect the scroll event with document.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll). However, scrolling down the buefy b-dropdown component triggered no scroll event.

How should I detect whether a scroll is happening or not?